# Color range of cells based on values in different sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 13 sheets in Google Sheets, 12 sheets having names in row and dates in column header.

I want the whole column to be grey-formatted based on holidays listed in a `"HolidayList"` sheet. I have written some code, which is not working at the proper cell address:

```js
function formatForHoliday() {
  Logger.clear();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var holidays = ss.getRange("HolidayList!A2:A80").getValues();
  // Logger.log(holidays);

  // For each sheet
  for ( var s = 0; s <= 12; s++ ) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[s];
    // Logger.log(sheet);
    var values = sheet.getRange(sheet.getName() + "!F3:NF3").getValues();
    // var newValues = [];
    // Logger.log(values);

    // In each sheet, for each value
    for (i in values[0]) {
      for (j in holidays) {
        var val = values[0][i];
        var hol = holidays[j][0];
        Logger.log(val.valueOf());
        Logger.log(hol.valueOf());

        if (val.valueOf() == hol.valueOf()) {
          // newValues.push(values[0][i]);
          var cellsRange = sheet.getRange(4, i + 6, 52, 1);
          var address = cellsRange.getA1Notation();
          cellsRange.setBackground('grey');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine, the only issue I can see right now is that you're fetching range of set[multiple] of cells but setting background to only one.

And you're applying setBackground() to a string. getA1Notation() returns string not range.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation

setBackground() can be applied to range only.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor

```
var cellsRange = sheet.getRange(4, i + 6, 52, 1);
var address = cellsRange.getA1Notation();
cellsRange.setBackground('grey');
```

Rather you should set to all of those cells whose range/address you have fetched.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor

I think what you should do is that :

1. You're doing step one i.e. fetching range correctly.

`var cellsRange = sheet.getRange(4, i + 6, 52, 1);`

2. Now you should make an array of same dimension as of *(4, i + 6, 52, 1)* i.e. I think [48X1]
3. Fill all it's element with 'grey'
4. Use **setBackgrounds()** method.
   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor

Let me know if this resolves your issue. Or if you have any further doubts/suggestions.

Thanks